# Issue Comparing items from two System.Drawing.Image Collections to see if they match

Tags: c#, wpf, image, observablecollection

I am making a picture puzzle game with drag and drop functionality in WPF. When an image is uploaded it is cut into 9 pieces and each bitmap is added to a collection (collection1) of System.Drawing.Images. It is this collection that I compare to, to see if the image when rearranged is correct. I then randomly assign each bitmap to a position on the grid and put into another collection (collection2) of System.Drawing.Images.

As I drag and drop an image on the grid, I change the images position in the collection2.
After I move an image on the grid I check (Validate) to see if the images position (index) in each collection matches. If so the picture has been rearranged. Hopefully, I have that explained right.

My issue is that the method always returns false, even when the images have been arranged to complete the image.

If I need to provide more code or explain better, please let me know. I want to make this clear to understand, but my head is fried

```
    public bool Validate(ObservableCollection<System.Drawing.Image> itemPlacement)
    {
        ObservableCollection<System.Drawing.Image> placement = itemPlacement;

        foreach (System.Drawing.Image item in placement)
        {
            if ((placement.IndexOf(item) != puzzlePiece.IndexOf(item) || placement.IndexOf(item) < 0))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you update collection2 with the new index?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you have 1 collection that stores a set of known images in a specific order and you have another collection (same images from the first collection) that represents the order the user placed them in and you want to determine if the orders match.  if they do, the user successfully solved the puzzle.

Well... easy enough - create a class with an index and compare that instead.

```
public class PuzzlePiece
{
  public int Index { get; set; }
  public Image Piece { get; set; }
}

for(int i = 0; i < puzzlePieces.Count; i++)
{
  if(puzzlePieces[i].Index != playerPieces[i].Index) return false;
}
return true;
```

Additionally, you could implement IComparable and sort based upon your index - but not likely needed in small collections when the images are added in order.  However, IComparable would allow you to say:

```
if(puzzlePieces[i].CompareTo(playerPieces[i]) != 0) return false;
```